# Limit a python file to only be run by a bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am looking for a way to limit how a python file to be called. Basically I only want it to be executable when I call it from a bash script but if ran directly either from a terminal or any other way I do not want it to be able to run. I am not sure if there is a way to do this or not but I figured I would give it a shot.

Comment: Your terminal is almost a bash (or other shell) script; or rather the other way around. I don't think this question makes much sense, to be honest.

Comment: Why do you (think you) want this? What are you *actually* trying to achieve?! Please see [*What is the XY problem?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731)

Comment: rather, you can check if some string is in `args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run it from the bash script with a special environment variable set, like:

```
FROM_BASH=1 /path/to/your_python_script.py
```

Then you check if the variable is set:

```
if os.environ.get('FROM_BASH'):
    # your exit code here
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no meaningful way to do this.

UNIX process architecture does not work this way. You cannot control the execution of a script by its parent process.

Instead we should discuss *why* you want to do something like this, you are probably thinking doing it in a wrong way and what good options there is to address the *actual* underlying problem.